# MySQL server startup error

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0, debian

**My Issue**

After shutting down and starting my system up, my MySQL daemon gives me this in the logs (the pertinent snippet is as follows):

```
2021-05-03T12:48:32.458594Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fut0lst.ic:86:addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA thread 139822345225984
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
12:48:32 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7fffe0c79cb0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
```

This is the second time I'm running into this issue. After struggling for a while the last time, I re-installed mysql server, which worked. I'm puzzled as to why this keeps happening and want to get to the root of the issue this time. I did nothing out of the ordinary (as far as I'm aware) to cause this error.

**Troubleshooting**

`innodb_force_recovery = 3` (not below) in my.cnf enables the daemon to run. According to [InnoDB recovery guide](https://forums.cpanel.net/resources/innodb-corruption-repair-guide.395/) and the official link in the error description this has something to do with "So for example: if your MySQL server starts up on mode 3, but not mode 2, it might be a safe assumption to say that the crash has something to do with the transaction rollback process." I've added `innodb_fast_shutdown = 0` and `innodb_purge_threads = 1` and dropped all the non-system schemas as well, but to no avail.

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` revealed an event listener and my current process, so I don't think there was much there.

Hdd space and memory is not an issue.

**And so...**

I'm not certain how to proceed with debugging from here on in. A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Two of the messages have hinted to hardware failure. If you have some bad blocks interfering with an InnoDB file, this could be a bad thing. Have you confirmed the health of the storage device?

Comment: @matigo I have seen that mentioned in several places though I certainly hope that's not the case. I'll get some software to scan the drive now.

Comment: check the system log for other anomaly's

Comment: @matigo After an overnight scan of several hours I learned that the drive is fine, thankfully. It's one of those things one postpones due to fear of bad news: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msGvEtmR970

Comment: @nbk Currently I'm using /var/log/mysql/error.log as a source to track the issue. I did read that the datadir might also contain .err files. I assume they will be relevant to the schemas i.e. mysql.err. I don't see anything like that though which further indicates that this issue can't be due to a corrupt index, hanging rollback or what have you. Which system log are you referring to?

Comment: @nbk Just a note so that my previous comment doesn't seem too stupid; I don't have a /var/log/syslog file

Comment: So, to get going, I've reinstalled mysql-server again. For now this is the only solution that works although hardly to be considered a solution.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/how-can-i-completely-reinstall-mysql